# RuntimeError: Function LeftMMFixedBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [5128, 5672] but expected shape compatible with [5672, 80]

Tags: python, deep-learning, knowledge-graph

When i start training of my model it give error in start first epoch.

Here is the message of full eror:

loading model from model/repro/wikimovie/best_model_doc                                                                 epoch 0                                                                                                                   0%|                                                                                        | 0/12022 [00:01<?, ?it/s] Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "main.py", line 156, in                                                                                      train(CFG)                                                                                                            File "main.py", line 64, in train                                                                                         loss.backward()                                                                                                       File "C:\guangting\anaconda\envs\qagnn\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245, in backward                          torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)                                    File "C:\guangting\anaconda\envs\qagnn\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_*init*_.py", line 147, in backward               allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag                                             RuntimeError: Function LeftMMFixedBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [5128, 5672] but expected shape compatible with [5672, 80]
I am trying to train my model. When i start training then on first epoch it give error of in invalid shape. on these line it give error:

`#here is my code:

```
def train(cfg):
    print("training ...")

    # prepare data
    entity2id = load_dict(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['entity2id'])
    word2id = load_dict(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['word2id'])
    relation2id = load_dict(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['relation2id'])

    train_documents = load_documents(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['train_documents'])
    train_document_entity_indices, train_document_texts = index_document_entities(train_documents, word2id, entity2id, cfg['max_document_word'])
    train_data = DataLoader(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['train_data'], train_documents, train_document_entity_indices, train_document_texts, word2id, relation2id, entity2id, cfg['max_query_word'], cfg['max_document_word'], cfg['use_kb'], cfg['use_doc'], cfg['use_inverse_relation']) 
    
    if cfg['dev_documents'] != cfg['train_documents']:
        valid_documents = load_documents(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['dev_documents'])
        valid_document_entity_indices, valid_document_texts = index_document_entities(valid_documents, word2id, entity2id, cfg['max_document_word'])
    else:
        valid_documents = train_documents
        valid_document_entity_indices, valid_document_texts = train_document_entity_indices, train_document_texts
    valid_data = DataLoader(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['dev_data'], valid_documents, valid_document_entity_indices, valid_document_texts, word2id, relation2id, entity2id, cfg['max_query_word'], cfg['max_document_word'], cfg['use_kb'], cfg['use_doc'], cfg['use_inverse_relation'])
    
    if cfg['test_documents'] != cfg['dev_documents']:
        test_documents = load_documents(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['test_documents'])
        test_document_entity_indices, test_document_texts = index_document_entities(test_documents, word2id, entity2id, cfg['max_document_word'])
    else:
        test_documents = valid_documents
        test_document_entity_indices, test_document_texts = valid_document_entity_indices, valid_document_texts
    test_data = DataLoader(cfg['data_folder'] + cfg['test_data'], test_documents, test_document_entity_indices, test_document_texts, word2id, relation2id, entity2id, cfg['max_query_word'], cfg['max_document_word'], cfg['use_kb'], cfg['use_doc'], cfg['use_inverse_relation'])

    # create model & set parameters
    my_model = get_model(cfg, train_data.num_kb_relation, len(entity2id), len(word2id))
    trainable_parameters = [p for p in my_model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(trainable_parameters, lr=cfg['learning_rate'])

    best_dev_acc = 0.0
    for epoch in range(cfg['num_epoch']):
        try:
            print('epoch', epoch)
            train_data.reset_batches(is_sequential = cfg['is_debug'])
            # Train
            my_model.train()
            train_loss, train_acc, train_max_acc = [], [], []
            for iteration in tqdm(range(train_data.num_data // cfg['batch_size'])):
                batch = train_data.get_batch(iteration, cfg['batch_size'], cfg['fact_dropout'])
                loss, pred, _ = my_model(batch)
                pred = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
                acc, max_acc = cal_accuracy(pred, batch[-1])
                train_loss.append(loss.item())
                train_acc.append(acc)
                train_max_acc.append(max_acc)
                # back propogate
                my_model.zero_grad()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(my_model.parameters(), cfg['gradient_clip'])
                optimizer.step()
            print('avg_training_loss', sum(train_loss) / len(train_loss))
            print('max_training_acc', sum(train_max_acc) / len(train_max_acc))
            print('avg_training_acc', sum(train_acc) / len(train_acc))

            print("validating ...")
            eval_acc = inference(my_model, valid_data, entity2id, cfg)
            if eval_acc > best_dev_acc and cfg['to_save_model']:
                print("saving model to", cfg['save_model_file'])
                torch.save(my_model.state_dict(), cfg['save_model_file'])
                best_dev_acc = eval_acc

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    # Test set evaluation
    print("evaluating on test")
    print('loading model from ...', cfg['save_model_file'])
    my_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(cfg['save_model_file']))
    test_acc = inference(my_model, test_data, entity2id, cfg, log_info=True)

    return test_acc
```

`